Plotting a filled circle at the boundary of pyplot axis. Can I prevent the circle being cut-off?
I want to plot a marker (filled circle) at a point on the graph of a function. Like in the following example:

I need to limit the x- and y-axis to [-5, 5] and [0, .4], respectively. Now the problem is that the marker should be at (-5, 0) and now it gets cut-off by these limits. Is there any way to plot the marker "above" everything else so that it doesn't get cut-off?
Here is the code to produce the example:
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

def pi(x):
   return stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)

pyplot.xlim(-5, 5)
pyplot.ylim(0, pi(0) + .01)

x = numpy.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
v = pi(x)

pyplot.plot(x, v, color = 'black')
pyplot.scatter(-5, 0, c = 'r', marker = 'o', s = 100)
pyplot.show()


pyplot.scatter(-5, 0, c = 'r', marker = 'o', s = 100, clip_on=False) ?
